# Select TOP or GROUP BY ranked data from nested SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table with events and results and query like this:

```
   SELECT T2.EventDate, T2.EventPlace, T2.Par1,
    T2.Par2, T2.Result, T2.ResultEventDate_sum 
    FROM
    (SELECT TOP 15 EventDate, EventPlace, Par1, Par2, 
    Result, SUM(Result) OVER (PARTITION BY EventDate) AS ResultEventDate_SUM
    FROM
        (SELECT EventDate, EventPlace, Par1, Par2, Result, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EventDate ORDER BY Result DESC) AS EventDate_rank
        FROM MainTable 
        WHERE AND CAST(UserNb AS int) = 103
              AND Col1 = 'X' AND Result > 0 AND Col2 LIKE '%Y%'
              AND Par1 > 500 AND Par1 <= 700) ranked
    WHERE EventDate_rank <= 5 ORDER BY ResultEventDate_sum DESC) T2
```

The results I get:

```
EventDate   EventPlace  Par1    Par2    Result  ResultEventDate_SUM
2019-05-26  PLACE nb  1 508      604    51.20   278.11
2019-05-26  PLACE nb  1 508      571    51.68   278.11
2019-05-26  PLACE nb  1 508      249    56.38   278.11
2019-05-26  PLACE nb  1 508       42    59.40   278.11
2019-05-26  PLACE nb  1 508       39    59.45   278.11
2019-06-09  PLACE nb  3 508      449    50.95   217.05
2019-06-09  PLACE nb  3 508      259    54.79   217.05
2019-06-09  PLACE nb  3 508      254    54.89   217.05
2019-06-09  PLACE nb  3 508      178    56.42   217.05
2019-06-16  PLACE nb  4 508      372    51.49   169.56
2019-06-16  PLACE nb  4 508       66    58.51   169.56
2019-06-16  PLACE nb  4 508       20    59.56   169.56
2019-06-02  PLACE nb  2 508      533    50.19   107.46
2019-06-02  PLACE nb  2 508      149    57.27   107.46
```

I need to get list of best (highest) sum of max 5 result from each event, but take only 3 best events. So I put SELECT TOP 15 (3 events by 5 results) and the query results is ok when there is a 5 results by each event. But if there is less then 5 results for each event I get also records from 4 event. How to modify query to be sure there will be only 3 events no matter how many results are for each one? In this example cut last 2 records (1 event with the smallest result 107.46). Is there a way to achieve this by simplify query without adding another code?

I tried to put COUNT(*) in the first line, but it counts the same like col resulteventdate, so I cannot use it as condition. Also If I added for ex. EXISTS, the statement is too big and take to much time.

Expected results is a table with only 3 events with best ResultEventDate_sum:

```
EventDate   EventPlace  Par1    Par2    Result  ResultEventDate_SUM
2019-05-26  PLACE nb  1 508      604    51.20   278.11
2019-05-26  PLACE nb  1 508      571    51.68   278.11
2019-05-26  PLACE nb  1 508      249    56.38   278.11
2019-05-26  PLACE nb  1 508       42    59.40   278.11
2019-05-26  PLACE nb  1 508       39    59.45   278.11
2019-06-09  PLACE nb  3 508      449    50.95   217.05
2019-06-09  PLACE nb  3 508      259    54.79   217.05
2019-06-09  PLACE nb  3 508      254    54.89   217.05
2019-06-09  PLACE nb  3 508      178    56.42   217.05
2019-06-16  PLACE nb  4 508      372    51.49   169.56
2019-06-16  PLACE nb  4 508       66    58.51   169.56
2019-06-16  PLACE nb  4 508       20    59.56   169.56
```

Thanks in advance for any tips.

UPDATE after tests:
Thanks to all of you. I tested your propositions in the query and Dense_Rank do the job correctly and quite fast. Helped me a lot.

Comment: Are you really working with SQL Server 2005?

Comment: Yep, still 2005

Comment: Then you really should consider upgrading. The 2008 version is about to go out of extended support. 2005 is not supported for a long time now...

Comment: That's the plan. I can't do it during season with those events, maybe when it's finished.

Comment: How to distinguish events from the result set you are showing? I mean is there any Event_Id? Also please add your expected output with the question. This will help.

Comment: mkRabbani, my mistake, there is an ID only in the MainTable. There is no other table with list of events, if I understand you corectly.

Comment: How do you define the top 3 events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one more window function i.e. Dense_Rank.
This may help you get required output.

```
select EventDate,EventPlace,Par1,Par2,Result,ResultEventDate_sum from(
SELECT T2.EventDate, T2.EventPlace, T2.Par1,
T2.Par2, T2.Result, T2.ResultEventDate_sum ,
DENSE_RANK()over(order by ResultEventDate_sum,T2.EventDate desc)rnk
FROM
(SELECT  EventDate, EventPlace, Par1, Par2, 
Result, SUM(Result) OVER (PARTITION BY EventDate) AS ResultEventDate_SUM
FROM
    (SELECT EventDate, EventPlace, Par1, Par2, Result, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EventDate ORDER BY Result DESC) AS 
            EventDate_rank
    FROM MainTable 
    WHERE AND CAST(UserNb AS int) = 103
          AND Col1 = 'X' AND Result > 0 AND Col2 LIKE '%Y%'
          AND Par1 > 500 AND Par1 <= 700) ranked
WHERE EventDate_rank <= 5  ) T2
 )T1 
 WHERE RNK<=3
```

Answer (score 1):

In this following query, I have considered EventPlace as Event_ID. This query will return TOP 3 Event (Based on SUM of Result per Event) Details (TOP 5 Rows for each Event)

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EventPlace ORDER BY EventPlace,Result DESC)  RN
    FROM your_table
    WHERE EventPlace IN
    (
        -- You can set any number based on 
        -- How many event details you wants to see
        SELECT TOP 3 EventPlace
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EventPlace ORDER BY EventPlace,Result DESC)  RN
            FROM your_table
        )A
        -- You can set any number based on 
        -- How many row's result you want to SUM for checking
        WHERE RN <= 5
        GROUP BY EventPlace
        ORDER BY SUM(Result) DESC
    )
)B
WHERE RN <= 5
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I made some tests and the first solution with Dense_Rank was faster, so I use that one. Your proposition is very flexible, so I regret,  tha I have no option here to set two answers as solution. Thank you very much.